# Get a list of media gallery images that contain label in Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9

I create a configurable product and I add some images with different labels. How I can get in the frontend in media.phtml file only the images that contain the label: *mylabel* and when I press on this images to have the functionality like more-views ? I have a code but I don't know why is display only the first image, not all.

[image]

```
$prodimg = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getMediaGalleryImages()->getItemByColumnValue('label','mylabel');
if ($prodimg != '') {
    echo "<img src='" .$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image', $prodimg->getFile()). "' class='img-responsive' />";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but breaking down your code example here are my thoughts:

```
$prodimg = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())
```

This is fine, although only do this if you need to retrieve attributes that don't exist already in `$_product`, otherwise you're just doubling the database queries.

```
->getMediaGalleryImages()
```

As per `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::getMediaGalleryImages()`, this returns a `Varien_Data_Collection`.

```
->getItemByColumnValue('label','mylabel')
```

As per `Varien_Data_Collection::getItemByColumnValue`, this will **only return a single item from the collection** that matches your criteria.

Instead, you probably want to use `->getItemsByColumnValue()` with the same arguments:

```
$productImages = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->load($_product->getId())
    ->getMediaGalleryImages()
    ->getItemsByColumnValue('label', 'mylabel');
```

From here, you *should* be able to just loop the array returned and output as you are already:

```
/** @var array $productImages */
foreach ($productImages as $productImage) { /** @var Varien_Object $productImage */
    $image = $this->helper('catalog/image')
        ->init($_product, 'image', $productImage->getFile());
    echo "<img src='" . $image . "' class='img-responsive' />";
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Robbie, your code work like a charm :)